# Is this function a Service Locator/Container?

Tags: php, design-patterns

```
function app($key = null, $value = null)
{
    if (null !== $key && null !== $value) {
        $GLOBALS['__app'][$key] = $value;
    }

    return (object) $GLOBALS['__app'];
}
```

So, I usually have a function like this and I store things like the Request and Session objects to use them anywhere in my application. For example:

```
app('req', new Request);
```

and then I use it like this:

```
app()->req->getMethod();
```

My question is, what exactly is this? Does this function act as a Service Locator and/or Service Container? I'm trying to document my code and I'm having trouble explaining this code.

Comment: this is a service locator, registry etc. it does have global state, which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hash map that creates global (app) variables. It's cast into an object so you can access its values with `app()->req` instead of `$map = app(); $value = $map['req']`

Comment: what makes it a service locator?

Comment: @DarthVader I'm not sure, but this isn't one, it's just a global map that you can put anything in it. You could use it as a service locator if you wanted, but if so, it's poorly designed because you can use it just to create global variables.

Comment: But it is a Service Container, then? I'm not sure I understand the difference between Container and Locator.

Comment: container `DI containers` deals with creating, disposing objects, lifetime of an object. locator is just a table, map to look up for objects . it doesnt do anything about creating instances.

Answer (score 0):

It is a service container, you can find more information here:

- [If Singletons are bad then why is a Service Container good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034748/if-singletons-are-bad-then-why-is-a-service-container-good)
- [Which pattern should I use for my unique instance of the User class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078562/which-pattern-should-i-use-for-my-unique-instance-of-the-user-class)

It's better than singleton because you can inject mocked objects, so it's much more unit testable

Comment: service container ? the container deals with lifetime of an object. in this case, there is no life time etc. this is straight a service locator, or registry or table. u name it.

Comment: The links you provided call it both Service Container AND Locator, and I'm not sure I understand the difference, if there is one!